# passenger 4 and apache is not using the right ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I've installed passanger to run as apache module, I installed passenger with `gem install passenger` as my user `ruby` in a rvm gemset while running ruby 2.1.2.

On apache this is my main configuration for passenger:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.50/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.50
  PassengerDefaultRuby /home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby
  PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
</IfModule>
```

My project uses a different ruby version and I want to use it, so on my virtualhost I'm setting `PassengerRuby`

```
PassengerRuby /home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@estas/wrappers/ruby
```

It exists, and I can use that ruby@gemset to launch for example `rails console`.

But when I go to the url it raises an error complaining about missing gems.

```
Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  /home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
....

Ruby interpreter command
  /home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby

Environment variables
rvm_bin_path = /home/ruby/.rvm/bin
GEM_HOME = /home/otheruser/deploy/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0
SHELL = /bin/bash
IRBRC = /home/ruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/.irbrc
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXU7p7Dp
MY_RUBY_HOME = /home/ruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2
PATH = /home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/home/ruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@myproject/bin:/home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/home/ruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/home/ruby/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home/otheruser/perl5/bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/otheruser/bin
```

Im curious about the `PATH`, why does it has both `ruby-2.1.2` and `ruby-2.2.1`? when running passenger, what sets this PATH?

What I'm doing wrongly or why this is not working? I'm doing this project to learn about capistrano and passenger, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The path is inherited from the user that launches passenger, so for apache this is likely www-data if you start apache via it's init script. You can look at /etc/paths or /etc/paths.d/ to see if anything is added there.